# use variables as key names when using numpy savez

Tags: python, numpy, save

After loading an npz file, I like being able to access arrays with keys, e.g.:

```
KEY1  = "names"
file  = np.load(npzFilename)
data  = file[KEY1]
```

But you have to manually force this when you save, i.e.:

```
np.savez(npzFilename, names=names)
```

Is there anyway to set the NPZ dictionary key using a variable?  i.e. something like

```
np.savez(npzFilename, names, key=KEY1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a dictionary you could do:

```
vals_to_save = {KEY1:names}
np.savez(npzFilename, **vals_to_save)
```

where you could set up the dict `vals_to_save` programatically as desired.